# Is there a from...import * equivalent of idaapi.require()?

Tags: ida, idapython, hexrays

[Loading your own modules from your IDAPython scripts with idaapi.require()](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=749) suggests using `idaapi.require()` to load user modules in IDAPython scripts. However in my script, I have extensively used `from <mymodule> import *` statement so that I don't need to prepend `mymodule` before every item I use. Is there any IDAPython equivalent to that?

Comment: Wouldn't you technically be allowed to use both? I.e. first use `idaapi.require()` ... if it fails the `from ... import ...` will anyway never get hit unless you somehow decided to ignore the possible failure `idaapi.require()` yields. No?